# findViewById() method returns null only sometimes (working fine most of the time)

Tags: android

I am facing a very strange issue here. In my `fragment`, After I `inflate` the `layout`, `findViewById()` method returns null sometimes. But the issue is not reproducible at all. I am getting these crash reports from Crashlytics. And this crash happened with one of the QA members also but then he was also not able to reproduce this issue.

Here is the code for my fragment

```
      @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
    ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);

    //Throwing Null Pointer Exception for the below line.
    back.someFunc();
    return customView;
 }
```

XML File:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/topics_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="?attr/default_background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/back_to_top_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/back_to_top_margin_bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/back"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/default_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Crash Logs

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.news.activities.NewsHomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3928)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
       at com.myapp.news.fragments.TopicsGroupFragment.onCreateView(TopicsGroupFragment.java:157)
       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1049)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1869)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreateCommon(Activity.java:5970)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3928)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Having a really hard time figuring out why `findViewById()` is returning null for that view.

Note : I have many `ImageView` `resources` whose id is `back` but they are all in different XML files.

Comment: `View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
    ImageView back= (ImageView) topicsView.findViewById(R.id.back);` ??

Should't it be `(ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);` ??

Comment: Where is `topicsView ` ? it should be `customView ` to access Views from layout if returning `customView ` from `onCreateView ` method

Comment: Why you use `topicsView` while you inflate layout in `customView`?

Comment: @all, It was a type error. I modified the variable name in one of the places and forgot to change in the other place for posting the question. I have modified the question.

Comment: please share custom_view XML

Comment: i had the same problem when i used the same id for different views. try different name and it will work fine.

Comment: What is with people downvoting the question? Do they have a solution for this problem?

Comment: @KhizarHayat: update the xml file.

Comment: @PareshMayani : updated the crash logs.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger  see my answer

Comment: @thedarkpassenger why didn't you return `return customView` inside `onCreateView` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: This code is not full code man. I have only posted snippet of the code.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: I will modify it in the question. thanks

Comment: I assume you've an empty constructor in the fragment. Do you have ?

Comment: please share your activity code when attaching that fragment.

Answer (score 6):

It may be because in `OnCreateView` the view is not fully created. Try to use the following code:

```java
/*---------- WHEN THIS FRAGMENT VIEW IS CREATING --------------------------*/
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
}

/*---------- WHEN FRAGMENT VIEW IS CREATED --------------------------*/
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageView back = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.someFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assign Custom View to `findviewbyId`. AS you are inflating your `Layout` in `customView`.

```
View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);
```

> Change your `Multiple image resources` id to unique for all.

For e.g `back` , `back1` , `back2` etc..

Comment: It was a type error. I modified the variable name in one of the places and forgot to change in the other place for posting the question. I have modified the question.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger Post your full crash Log. And `customview.xml` code also.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you are calling it too early.

Wait until onFinishInflate(). Here is a sample project demonstrating a custom View accessing its contents.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Jank/ThreePaneBC

Answer (score 1):

Use OnCreateView to set the layout to your fragment and use onActivityCreated to create object to your views like following code.

```
public class test extends Fragment
{
    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView back= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.back);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating your view in variable named **customView** And you are using  **topicsView** view for Imageview ,Thats why you are getting Nullpointer Exception.

```
 Lets See the full code.       


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
    ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);

    back.someFunc();
    return customView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating view into customView while you are using topicsView to find its id....

Change topicsView to customView

```
ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);
```

Comment: It was a type error. I modified the variable name in one of the places and forgot to change in the other place for posting the question. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are inflating your view in variable named `customView` And you are using  `topicsView` view for Imageview , which is wrong .

Here is the full code

```
    @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
    ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);


    back.someFunc();
    return customView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid crash make a null check

```
   @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View customView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, container, false);
ImageView back= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.back);

if(back!=null)
back.someFunc();
 }
```